# Setting up simple HelloWorld JAX-WS WebService with Java Spring MVC framework?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jax-ws

Please forgive this noobster. I have tried using several tutorials for getting up and running a simple HelloWorld JAX-WS web service with Java Spring MVC 3.0

Can you please recommend me any book to get some upto date knowledge about spring MVC3 and web services in it or some real basic, up to date and working tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/) - JSR-224 standard for Java SOAP web services with a set of annotations and focus on JAXB
- [Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site) - proprietary SpringSources' framework for developing contract-first (XML schema based) web services, not compliant with JAX-WS
- [JAX-RS](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) - JSR-311 standard for Java REST web services
- [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) - SpringSources' web MVC framework. Can also be used to develop REST (but not JAX-RS compliant) services.

As you can see Spring MVC has nothing to do with JAX-WS.

Comment: can I use Spring-WS with simple SpringMVC prroject by importing some of its libraries abd following some tutorial?

Comment: @AqifHamid: of course, especially various Spring libraries integrate and play nicely with each other.